# Process file in multiple threads C++

Tags: c++, concurrency, ifstream

I've been trying to process words of an `input.txt` file which basically consists of a large text (variable size). The idea is to split this file and process it by chunks in multiple threads (for simplicity I will ignore the multithreading part, but at the end that will be my purpose). So for example, given this text:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n
The quick brown fox jumps\n
over the lazy dog
```

If I want to compute this file in 6 different threads, I'd split it in this 6 chunks:

`The quick brown fox jumps` (note a space at the end)

`over the lazy dog\n`

`The quick brown fox jumps` (note a space at the end)

`over the lazy dog\n`

`The quick brown fox jumps\n`

`over the lazy dog`

For doing this, I would have something similar to:

```
std::ifstream file("input.txt");
file.seekg(0, file.end);
int length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);

int chunkLength = length/numThreads;
for(i=0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    processChunk(i*chunkLength, (i+1)*chunkLength+1);
}
```

The processChunk function would be something similar to this (ignoring threads for simplicity):

```
void processChunk(int initPos, int endPos) {
    std::ifstream file("input.txt");
    file.seekg(initPos);
    // process it until endPos is reached
    file.close()
}
```

My main concern is in the logic for splitting the files, because I should make sure to split by words, so if a split is int the character `m` from `example`, I should decrease the start and end pointers to reach a `\n` or a `whitespace` (so until the `e` character).

But this implies a lot of assumptions, like thinking that `input.txt` won't contain a word which overlaps more than two chunks, and some others.

I was wondering if there is a better way of splitting the file by words for processing the chunks independently and as fast as possible which doesn't involve this kind of assumptions.

Thanks!

Comment: I/O is slow, so you don't want to do that six times. Read the whole file in once, into a `string` or `vector<char>`, then use threads to process chunks of that sequence.

Comment: @JonathanWakely What if the file is over 3GB?

Comment: @lpares12 What difference does that make? If you are using threads it is all shared memory anyway? Opening the file 6 different times isnt going to reduce time to read or memory usage.

Comment: If you really want to do it this way the solution seems pretty simple. Seek to `initPos` then if `initPos!=0` and the character at that position isn't a whitespace character keep going until you find the end of the current word, and start from there instead. When you reach `endPos` if that isn't a whitespace character keep going until the end of the current word, and stop there instead.

Comment: (3GB isn't very big, get a bigger computer ;-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely but isn't it better to have 6 file descriptors pointing to the same file at different positions than loading the whole file (over `x` GB) into memory?

Comment: @JonathanWakely that is not really true. One can have RAID array and have a need to read large file (few GB) which is definitely a good setup for reading in several threads. OP - regarding the processing - probably we may need more information to suggest something. In some cases you may actually need to load the whole file into memory.

Comment: @Chaosit I want to achieve something like the Map function does in MapReduce, so splitting a file and processing it in different "nodes", in this case, threads.

Comment: One of my suggestions will be to try doing it in the following way (this implies that you have a clear way of identifying the end of the chunk and this is purely serial algorithm): have the first thread read the last character of it's chunk if that's not the end of a chunk - seek left or right. When you find the end of a chunk - set it as the start for the second thread. Second thread does the same thing, etc. And then you can read the whole file in threads. This can ONLY be beneficial with large files and I do not know if this is really true or not. Otherwise I can suggest trying MPI IO.

Comment: Just have one thread read the file line by line and spawn threads to do the work on each line.

Comment: How do you know your chunks won't split a word?  If you're processing text, you'd be better served with a producer-consumer model where the producer is a thread reading lines from the file with N consumers processing lines.  That would even be likely to improve IO performance because you'd be streaming the file from beginning to end, allowing caching and read-ahead to help.  Parallel IO on "normal" single-device file systems generally slows things down.

Comment: Ok I'd suggest to follow @AndrewHenle advice rather than mine if you are not working with a cluster.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks. So this would only be helpful in case I have the file split in different chunks in a distributed system or something similar?

Comment: You want to use memory mapped i/O and then map the buffer to an streambuf and use that with an istream instance in case you want to use iostreams. Otherwise use the memory mapped buffer directly.

Comment: @steve *You want to use memory mapped i/O ...* Not in this case.  Per one [Linus Torvalds](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2): "People love mmap() and other ways to play with the page tables to
optimize away a copy operation, and sometimes it is worth it.

HOWEVER, playing games with the virtual memory mapping is very expensive
in itself.  **It has a number of quite real disadvantages that people tend
to ignore** ..."

Comment: @lpares12 *So this would only be helpful in case I have the file split in different chunks in a distributed system or something similar?*  Do you mean performing I/O with multiple threads? If so, then that's something you'd only really want to do for either distributed systems (as you say) or if the file is stored on a complex multi-device file system where data can be spread over multiple devices.  Something like IBM's GPFS:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_General_Parallel_File_System  In general, unless you're on such a system, multithreaded I/O will just slow things down.

Comment: Nope, use one thread to do the memory mapped i/o and then spread it over several worker threads to process the data.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Care to give a reason why this wouldn't be a good application of mmaps? Yes, it has disadvantages but this seems to be a pretty decent application of it.

Comment: @mascoj `mmap()` is almost *never* the fastest way to read data.  In some use-cases, it's a really easy way to access a moderate amount of data randomly - `mmap()` the file, then access the data as an array that's in memory. It works, it's simple and you have to make an actual effort to introduce bugs. But the performance only begins to approach regular I/O if the data is accessed enough that the expensive virtual-to-physical mappings and TLB updates. Read the link: `mmap()` has "quite noticeable setup and teardown costs", "page faulting is expensive", "it's quite slow".

Comment: @mascoj (cont) [Read the link](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2).  Torvalds concludes with "just copying the data once) is probably pessimal
for mmap()."  And that's the use-case here - read through the data once.  Pay the price to create all those virtual-to-physical mappings, page fault the data in, then throw those pages away once the process has moved on.  That just can't compare to the performance that can be obtained by using OS-specific options such as `O_DIRECT`. If `mmap()` is so great, why don't databases such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, or Oracle use it for I/O?

Comment: @mascoj Again, quoting Torvalds:  "People love mmap() and other ways to play with the page tables to
optimize away a copy operation, and sometimes it is worth it.  HOWEVER, playing games with the virtual memory mapping is very expensive
in itself.  It has a number of quite real disadvantages that people tend
to ignore..."

Comment: It hasn't been mentioned which platform is used. You are jumping to conclusions here. The advantage of memory mapped i/o is saving the effort to copy the memory from kernel to user memory. The advantage of direct i/o is avoiding the buffer cache. Actually some database use memory mapped i/o. What has been posted so far is mostly guesses. The engineering way is to implement the different approaches and measure.